# LookerStudio Linking API pageId parameter not working

Tags: looker-studio

I specified pageId like this ( it is published sample report page)

◆original URL
https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/f1a27d0f-7fa7-46f7-8803-e8a1f0beb443/page/rJxg

◆created URL(made by LinkingAPI)
https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/create?c.reportId=f1a27d0f-7fa7-46f7-8803-e8a1f0beb443&c.pageId=p_88b3jlgqmc
⇒ intent to get to pageId p_88b3jlgqmc clicked by, but go to default top page

but open with default first top page. What is it wrong??

1. I tried copy and pasted correct pageId (extracted from report page)
2. I read looker studio linking API documentation and not wrong grammer for specifie access page

Google Linking API doc page here
https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/integrate/linking-api